# Defining shelve(inventory,product_list): it pertains to dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.5

The problem:

This is the last question for a homework assignment and it is causing me the most trouble. I have spent so much time on it and yet I can not get the right results. I am not sure what the error is, I am assuming that it is a logic one. Instead of trying to summarize, I will copy the assignment in its entirety, to avoid confusion. A detailed response explaining how the solution was reached would be also helpful, for I would like to gain a better understanding of this concept.

We want to track the inventory at our store by tracking how many items of each
product we currently have. We will use a dictionary with name:amount key-value
pairs. The name is a string, the amount is an integer.

We will define the shelve function, which accepts a dictionary as the inventory
and a list of (name, number) pairs that each indicate we should update the inventory of that named product by adding number to it. (the number could be
negative). This second argument is named product_list.
When a product is mentioned for the first time, it will need to be added to the
inventory dictionary. When its count reaches zero, it should remain in the 
inventory with the zero count. But the count must never become negative.
If the inventory for any particular item ever becomes negative, you must raise
a ValueError to indicate that the amount of some product is below zero.
- Return Value: None. (make changes to the inventory in place).
 - Suggestion: use try-except blocks to add items. (You might find other solutions though, and that's okay).
- Requirement: raise ValueErrors whenever an item's count goes negative; use
the string "negative amount for product" when constructing the Exception.

Example:

```
d = {"apple":50, "pear":30, "orange":25}

ps = [("apple",20),("pear",-10),("grape",18)] 

shelve(d,ps)
d 
{'pear': 20, 'grape': 18, 'orange': 25, 'apple': 70}

shelve(d,[("apple",-1000)])
Traceback (most recent call last):

ValueError: negative amount for apple
```

My code:

```
def shelve(inventory,product_list):
    invt = {}
    count = 0
    try:
        for x in product_list:
            if x== True:
                invt{x} = product_list.shelve{x}
                count += key

    except ValueError:
    print ('negative amount for (product)')
```

Other examples:

Check that `d = {"apple":50} shelve(d,[("apple",20),("apple",-30)])` modifies `d` to be `{"apple":40}`.

Check that `shelve({}, [("apple",-20)])` raises a `ValueError`.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What happens if you do `shelve({}, [('apple', -20), ('apple, 30)])` should it raise a ValueError or `{'apple' : 10}`?

Comment: you've got `except except ValueError` there - should that just be `except ValueError`?

Comment: @StevenSummers I believe it should return   {'apple' : 10}

Comment: @RobGwynn-Jones it should just be except ValueError, I edited the mistake. My apologies

Answer (score 1):

Given the answers to the comments and assuming you need to avoid side-effects if any inventory item would go below `0`:

```
def shelve(inventory, product_list):
    adj = dict(inventory)
    for product, amount in product_list:
        adj[product] = adj.get(product, 0) + amount

    if any(v < 0 for v in adj.values()):
        raise ValueError("Negative amount for product")

    inventory.update(adj)

>>> d = {"apple":50, "pear":30, "orange":25}
>>> shelve(d, [("apple",20),("pear",-10),("grape",18)])
>>> d
{'apple': 70, 'grape': 18, 'orange': 25, 'pear': 20}
>>> shelve(d,[("apple",-1000)])
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: Negative amount for product
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if some value in the dictionary becomes negative after adding some number to it, then you raise the ValueError exception and reverse the operation.

```
def shelve(inventory, product_list):
    # Here you iterate through the product_list.
    for p in product_list:      
        # The product_list contains pairs (tuples), e.g. ('apple', 20) and you
        # check if the first element of the pair, i.e. p[0] exists as a key 
        # in the dictionary.
        if p[0] in inventory:   
            # You use try-except to raise and then handle the exception 
            try:
                # If key p[0] exists in the dictionary then you add the value from the pair, i.e. p[1] to existing key's value in the dictionary  
                inventory[p[0]] += p[1]
                # If the value of the key p[0] is negative you raise an exception with the message in the parentheses 
                if inventory[p[0]] < 0:
                    raise ValueError('negative amount for product')
            # Here you handle the exception. You print the message and subtract the value you added. 
            except ValueError as ve:
                print(ve)
                inventory[p[0]] -= p[1]
        # If the key p[0] does not exist in the dictionary, then you add it to the dictionary and assign value p[1] to it.  
        else:
            inventory[p[0]] = p[1]
    #Here you just print the contents of inventory
    print(inventory)        

# These are just examples to test the code.
d = {"apple":50, "pear":30, "orange":25}
ps = [("apple",20),("pear",-10),("grape",18)] 

shelve(d, ps)
shelve(d,[("apple",-1000)])
```

This is just an example of how you can solve your assignment. There are other (probably much better) variants as well.

Comment: Can you explain what you did? I am not positive on what you did.

Comment: @Soccerninja I added the comments. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will perform the necessary checks (read comments):

```
d = {"apple":50, "pear":30, "orange":25}
ps = [("apple",20),("pear",-10),("grape",18)]


def shelve(sh: dict, items: list) -> dict:
    for name, value in items:  # iterate over list and split tuples
        if name not in sh:  # add item key if it doesn't already exist
            sh[name] = 0

        if sh[name] + value < 0:  # raise ValueError if sum will be negative
            raise ValueError('negative amount for (%s)' % name)

        sh[name] += value  # apply change to dictionary

    return sh  # not necessary but can be good for testing
```

This code should be fairly fast as it doesn't spend time iterating over the entire dictionary.